# How can i delay image upload in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am working on an app that allows a user to capture an image and upload it.

The uploading process is done in the background, which means that while one upload is in progress, the user can capture and upload more images; or he can navigate to other pages.

I am using ASIHTTP to upload the image.

I have heard that if images are above a certain size, it may cause some problems. How can i handle this?

Comment: Where did you hear that ?

Comment: what problem you heard?

Comment: please add some code.your problem explain.

Comment: As long as the user has control (i.e. The user chooses when to capture or upload the image), there will be no issue with bandwidth usage. If you need further help, provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies :) What i heard is, in the case of slow internet, if the upload queue gets longer, the app may get unresponsive or upload process will get cancelled completely.

Comment: @MarcusAdams i didnt quite got what u said..by user you meant the person using the app or the programmer??

Comment: @user1922941, the person using the app is the user.

Comment: your question is not well formatted.please re check.

Comment: @MarcusAdams my question was a dumb one right?? :)but i am confused Marcus.Suppose if the user attending some function and he is continuously uploading some snaps and (to make things worse )the wifi there is slow,is there a way i can handle this within the app without bothering the user??

Comment: @sagarcool89 I am new here. What did i do wrong??

Comment: @user1922941 you didn't wrong anything,but you should ask well formatted question so everyone understands what you want actually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but some useful comments:
1. drop ASIHTTP if you can. It's not maintained and there are much better libraries out there. Try AFNetworking. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
2. find out where you heard that large images are problematic. If it's a problem with ASIHTTP, more the better reason to ditch it.
3. your question was ok, but best to show some code of what you're trying, or reference the image upload issue.
4. If you haven't already, read through the https://stackoverflow.com/help sections to get a better feel for what others expect when you ask a question.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sometimes it's hard to please people when you are new to asking questions. :-)